# Check if website is liked on FB or FB Like Button in VB. NET App

Tags: .net, facebook, visual-studio-2010, button, facebook-like

-Hey everyone , id like to make an app that can check if the person already liked my website on facebook or google + as alternative if fb is too complicated .

-The other thing is to make a button that will like certain URL when clicked ,or prompt Fb login if person is not logged in. now i dont know if this is posible in VB 2010 .

Can anyone post if and how these 2 things can be done in VB .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate with Facebook, you need to you their graph API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

This can be called using standard HTML and Javascript. What you need to do in VB, is to integrate a web interface where you call the graph API.

The link to Facebook's Graph API documentation given above is very self explanatory. Please let me know if you have further questions on this topic.

Comment: Hey , Thanks for answer , ill take a look at it , maybe it is out of my skill range for now . How would a code look like for basic button for liking an URL ? do i need a web browser or it can be done in background ?